# Batch rename files using directory name with Regular Expression

Tags: regex, file

Given the following file/directory structure:

```
/photos/1/original/filename1.jpg
/photos/1/thumb/filename1.jpg
/photos/2/original/filename2.jpg
/photos/2/thumb/filename2.jpg
/photos/3/original/filename3.jpg
/photos/3/thumb/filename3.jpg
```

...etc. I'm looking for the regexp to convert the file/directory structure to:

```
/photos/1/original.jpg
/photos/1/thumb.jpg
/photos/2/original.jpg
/photos/2/thumb.jpg
/photos/3/original.jpg
/photos/3/thumb.jpg
```

...etc. I've got scripts to do the file renaming in ruby or perl...just missing the proper regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl solution

```
$newfn = $oldfn;
$newfn =~ s/(original|thumb)[^\.]*/$1/;
rename($oldfn, $newfn);
```

As requested, to match any keyword, not just "original" or "thumb", assuming that the /photos/nn remains the same:

```
$newfn = $oldfn;
$newfn =~ s?(photos/\d+/[^/]*)/[^\.]*?$1?;
rename($oldfn, $newfn);
```

Adapting this solution to also remove the directories if they are empty

```
$newfn = $oldfn;
$newfn =~ s?(/photos/\d+/)([^/]*)/[^\.]*?$1$2?;
rename($oldfn, $newfn);
unlink($1$2);
```

I'm not sure what this will do if the directory is not empty when you go to unlink it.

Comment: Would you be able to offer a more generic solution? So, if say there were more folder names than just thumb or original, would it be possible to change your exp to account for any x folder names? Thanks Paul.

Comment: Does that do the job in the first place?

Comment: Well, you have to actually move the file afterwards - I was just giving you the regexp to generate the new file name.

Comment: This could be achieved by evaluating "rename($oldfn, $newfn);" correct? If so, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Working now, thanks Paul. How about cleanup? i.e. removing the old folders?

Comment: I left out a "*".  That's why it wasn't working when you tested it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a ruby solution:

```
require 'fileutils'

old_file = "/photos/1/original/filename1.jpg"
new_file = old_file.sub(/(\d+)\/(\w+)\/.+(\.\w+)/, '\1/\2\3')
FileUtils.mv(old_file, new_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapting Paul Tomblin's solution and providing the more generic renaming:

```
my $newfn = $oldfn;
$newfn =~ s%(/\d+/[^/]+)/[^/]+(\.[^./]+)$%$1$2%;
```

Let's expand that with the 'x' option:

```
$newfn =~ s%
                (              # start remembering
                /\d+/          # /397/
                [^/]+          # original, thumb, othername, ...
                )              # stop remembering
                /              # directory
                [^/]+          # filename within directory
                (\.[^./]+)$    # remember extension matching to end of name
           %
                $1$2           # /397/original.png
           %x;
```

(Untested - there could be typos.)

Answer (score 0):

Note:  While this doesn't directly answer your question, I think you'll still find this useful.  Linux and cygwin both have commands "`rename`" and "`mmv`" (multiple move), which can meet this need.  Given your directory structure and your request, you can trivially use the `rename` command to solve this problem:

```
cd /photos/1/original
rename filename original *.jpg
mv *.jpg ..
cd ../thumb
rename filename thumb *.jpg
mv *.jpg ..
cd ../2
  .... (repeat for other directories)
```

You'll have to check the man page for `mmv`,  but it looks like you can do something like (this is untested):

```
cd /photos
mmv "*/original/filename*.jpg" "./#1/original#2.jpg"
mmv "*/thumb/filename*.jpg" "./#1/thumb#2.jpg"
```

and this will both rename the file and move the file into the desired directory for the whole tree of files that you wish to handle.  The double-quotes are mandatory.